# Firefox throws error - regular expression too complex

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox4

I'm doing a load() on a page using Jquery, using Jquery Minified 1.3.2 and in ff4, it's telling me regular expression is too complex, and not completing the load.  Works with no errors at all in chrome.  Any idea what's going on?  Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Try using the non-minified version. Preferably try 1.5.2. See which line causes the error.

Comment: Maybe the expression holds to much data for firefox, but chrome has a higher default.  Could you post the expression?

Comment: besides the line number, maybe a snippet of the code, so we can actually see what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: 1.3.2?  Really? That's over 2 years old ...

Comment: I know but I have to use 1.3.2 because drupal breaks if I don't for some reason.  How could an expression hold too much data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just ran into the same error in FF4 (NOT in FF3.6).  We're running jQuery 1.4.4.

For us, the issue was a bad jQuery selector.  Namely:

**$("#top *[contenteditable=true")**

When it should have been:

**$("#top *[contenteditable=true]")**

That missing right bracket fixed it.  I recommend double-checking your selectors.

Comment: In my troubleshooting, I also tested jQuery 1.5.1 with the same results.